# Storing variables for persistent HTTP connection WITHOUT COOKIES in FLASK

Tags: python, http, flask, backbone.js, server

I want to store variables for every persistent HTTP connection made in flask. In other words, I need to store some variables for every client.
The catch is, I have to do this without cookies. Which means I need to store the data on the server. Well, I can create a dictionary, but can I differentiate between different clients throughout the connections?

Any help would be awesom! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the `session` object, refer to this [topic](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#sessions) from official `Flask` documentation.

> In addition to the request object there is also a second object called session which allows you to **store information specific to a user from one request to the next**. This is **implemented on top of cookies** for you and signs the cookies cryptographically. What this means is that **the user could look at the contents of your cookie but not modify it**, unless they know the secret key used for signing.

but beer in mind that `session` are stored in a `cookie` on the **client side**. Fortunately `Flask-Session` [extension](https://flasksession.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) solves this limitation of `Flask` and it even lets you choose the storage method : File system, databases, Redis ...

i recommend you this [video](https://youtu.be/WsoL4MIhJbg) from [pretty printed](http://%20http://prettyprinted.com) to get things clear and try to run the code in chrome for e.g, open 2 sessions, the 2nd one in `private mode` if OK then try to install `Flask-Session`.

Comment: That's a great idea! Thanks. But as far as I know a sessionID is still stored in the Client's browser :/ I cant't use cookies due to privacy reasons unfortunately. I know that you can save the sessionID in the body if you implement your own Session. But that just is far too difficult for me to do. Maybe there is an easier way?